# Valores do formulário HTML não estão variando dentro do while PHP

Tags: php, html

Pois bem, fiz um extrato que seleciona os dados do DB e os imprime na tela através do while, que está gerando os valores corretos, porém agora estou tentando criar um botão editar que abre um popup com os inputs já preenchidos com os valores, porém esse form só está recebendo os valores do 1º loop. Alguém tem alguma sugestão para resolver o problema?

**Segue o código que estou tentando arrumar:**

```
while($linha=$buscarextrato->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '
<div class="div" style="border:0px;width:80px;">
    <div data-role="popup" id="Popup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:500px;">
            <form style="display:inline;" name="lanc" action="editalanc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <input type="hidden" name="numlanc" value="'.$linha[lancamento].'"/>
                <input type="date" name="data" value="'.$linha[data].'"/>
                <input type="number" name="debito" value="'.$linha[debito].'"/>
                <input type="number" name="credito" value="'.$linha[credito].'"/>
                <input type="number" name="valor" value="'.$linha[valor].'"/>
                <input type="text" name="descricao" value="'.$linha[descricao].'"/>
            </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#Popup" data-rel="popup"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
</div>
    ';
```

**código JS obtido por referência:**

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

**OBS:** Os valores gerados (linha) variam corretamente em cada loop, a única coisa que não muda é o form, me parece que ele recebe o valor do 1 loop e ignora o restante.

Comment: Provavelmente o seu erro está no JavaScript, tentando abrir o *popup* através do id `#Popup`. Como o atributo `id` define um elemento único do DOM, ele sempre será o primeiro formulário. Você precisará mudar isso para corrigir o problema, seja gerando `ids` únicos para cada formulário, seja mudando a forma de referenciá-lo.

Comment: no caso estou usando jquery, não tenho idéia de como modificar o código, devo mudar a forma de fazer isso então?

Comment: Sim, mas primeiro edite sua pergunta e adicione seu código JS que trata do popup.

Comment: o source está nos links que postei acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, como sugerido por **Anderson Carlos Woss** o problema estava no ID do popup que era o mesmo em todos os casos, através de uma gambiarra fiz o seguinte:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="Popup'.linha[lancamento].'" class="ui-content" style="min-width:500px;">
```

Concatenei com a linha do lancamento que é única para gerar um popup em cada loop.
Fiz o mesmo para o botão que o referência.

```
<a href="#Popup'.linha[lancamento].'" data-rel="popup"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetchAll` ao invés de `fetch`

O `fetch` vai te retornar um array simples, é ideal quando há somente um registro, já `fetchAll` retornará uma matriz com todos os resultados.

Comment: Pode citar a fonte que diz o que afirmou na resposta? Por quê o `fetch` não é indicado para múltiplos registros? E qual a relação disso com o problema da pergunta, visto que os registros estão sendo listados corretamente?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, entendi muito mal a pergunta, em relação ao que afirmei, qualquer um sabe que usar funções nativas tem um desempenho maior, pode ser milissegundos dependendo dos registros, mas a questão que é, que se existe um função justamente para esse propósito por que não usá-la? De acordo com a documentação fetch retorna a linha seguinte, e fetchAll todas as linhas, e a discussão devia parar por ai, não se trata de referência e sim interpretação de texto. (A propósito, nesse caso aí,  todos os benchmarks que vi até hoje, dão resultados positivos para o fetchAll)

Comment: Sim, a diferença estaria em armazenar todos os registros em memória ou não. O `fetchAll` armazena todos em memória, enquanto o `fetch` armazena apenas um registro por vez, somente quando for utilizado. Eu particularmente não vejo motivos para se utilizar o `fetchAll` aqui, pois não há a necessidade de se ter todos os dados em memória.